# WIFI is disabled by hard switch hp 430

Tags: wireless, 14.04, wifi-hardware-switch

I searched and tried many things to resolve this issue but nothing helped me. Please find the methods below that I tried.

OS: ubuntu 14.04
Laptop: HP 430 (64 bit)

1. Checked the radio transmitter kernel subsystem `rfkill list all`

   Output:

   ```
   0: hci0: Bluetooth
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
   1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
       Soft blocked: yes
       Hard blocked: yes
   2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
       Soft blocked: yes
       Hard blocked: yes
   3: phy0: Wireless LAN
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: yes
   ```

   Based on the above output, it is a hardware lock. So, Checked/Changed the **BIOS** configuration settings for hot keys or `fn+F1 ..F12`

   By referring [this](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht072691) link. But no help.
2. I suspected drivers. So, I cross checked the drivers and followed the procedure which is mentioned in this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558) - Sadly no help
3. I decided to disable the hot keys function itself and I followed this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2231243) for that. Again no help.

If you are not able to give solution for the hard lock issue. I am fine with enabling the wifi in startup also

Edited: Added more information about system drivers, etc

Input:$ `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Output:$

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
            Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:3672]
            Kernel driver in use: r8169
        --
        02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
            Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1461]
            Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Input:$ `iwconfig`

Output:$

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
  Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
  Power Management:off
```

Input:$ `lsmod`

Output:$

```
Module                  Size  Used by
    talpa_vfshook          35673  1 
    talpa_pedconnector     12509  0 
    talpa_pedevice         13516  2 talpa_pedconnector
    talpa_vcdevice         13082  10 
    talpa_core             91941  3 talpa_vfshook,talpa_vcdevice
    talpa_linux            34428  4 talpa_vfshook,talpa_vcdevice,talpa_core
    talpa_syscallhook      20264  1 talpa_vfshook
    rfcomm                 69160  8 
    bnep                   19624  2 
    arc4                   12608  2 
    ath9k                  92258  0 
    ath9k_common           25637  1 ath9k
    ath9k_hw              424791  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
    ath                    29006  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
    parport_pc             32701  0 
    ppdev                  17671  0 
    bcma                   52096  0 
    mac80211              560377  1 ath9k
    snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46368  1 
    snd_hda_codec_realtek    65580  1 
    cfg80211              505934  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
    hp_wmi                 14062  0 
    sparse_keymap          13948  1 hp_wmi
    compat                 13849  4 cfg80211,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
    ssb                    62379  0 
    uvcvideo               80885  0 
    videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
    videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
    videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
    videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
    intel_rapl             18773  0 
    x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
    intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
    coretemp               13435  0 
    kvm_intel             143060  0 
    snd_hda_intel          56451  3 
    snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
    snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
    kvm                   451511  1 kvm_intel
    crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
    crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
    snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
    ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
    cryptd                 20359  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
    snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
    wmi                    19177  1 hp_wmi
    joydev                 17381  0 
    snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
    snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
    snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
    i915                  783805  3 
    drm_kms_helper         53081  1 i915
    snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
    snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
    video                  19476  1 i915
    snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
    drm                   303102  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
    hp_wireless            12637  0 
    snd                    69322  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
    btusb                  32412  0 
    serio_raw              13462  0 
    bluetooth             391136  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
    mac_hid                13205  0 
    lpc_ich                21080  0 
    mei_me                 18627  0 
    mei                    82276  1 mei_me
    soundcore              12680  1 snd
    rtsx_pci_ms            18151  0 
    i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
    memstick               16966  1 rtsx_pci_ms
    lp                     17759  0 
    parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
    rtsx_pci_sdmmc         23274  0 
    ahci                   25819  2 
    libahci                32716  1 ahci
    psmouse               106678  0 
    r8169                  67581  0 
    rtsx_pci               45956  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
    mii                    13934  1 r8169
```

Comment: Does your wireless come to life if you do: sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi Thanks.

Comment: I tried it. Wifi is not coming to life but bluetooth. Also I tried adding like this `echo "options hp_wmi wireless=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/hp.conf` - no help

Comment: Please see _modinfo hp-wmi._ wireless=1 is not an available parameter and will be ineffective. Why are the Broadcom drivers _bcma_ and _ssb_ loaded?